# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español que describa bien el sentido negativo de "entitlement" en inglés?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En inglés usan la palabra "entitlement" para referirse al que cree que tiene derecho a todo, o algo así. Por ahí lo describieron como "aquellos que creen que tienen derecho a lo mejor de la vida".

Usando el traductor te lo traduce simplemente como "derecho" o "autorización" pero no es lo mismo.

¿Existe alguna palabra en español que describa bien el sentido negativo de "entitlement" en inglés?

Comment: Entitled can have a neutral sense as well. So when you have enough reputation on this site you are entitled to view the review queues. It does also have the slightly pejorative sense you mention of people who think they deserve something even though they have done nothing to justify it. I have no idea whetehr Spanish distinguishes these.

Comment: @mdewey I agree with you that "entitled" and "entitlement" are neutral in English. I see them all the time in my legal translations. It's hard to think of examples where it has a negative connotation, unless it is embedded within a larger construction like "He thinks he is only one entitled to...", "He has a sense of absolute entitlement", etc.

Comment: Hasta donde se, no existe. Pero en jerga si existe.

Comment: No hay que confundir lo que se llama "entitlements" como la seguridad social en Estados Unidos con la expresión to be entitled to something. I'm entitled to give my opinion here. Tengo el derecho de dar mi opinión aqui. Es simplesmente: tener derecho a algo. No es nada complicado. Sentirse con el derecho de [decir x]; to feel entitled to [say x]

Comment: Muy cierto lo que dice @Lambie. La acepción de "entitlement" en inglés es negativa solo en algunos casos. En otros representa derechos adquiridos (y en el caso de Seguro Social, pagados en su totalidad).

Comment: @walen Excuse me but my English is 100% native. I am not confusing anything at all:  Mr. X feels entitled to Y. = Mr. X has a sense of entitlement. The negative meaning can be conveyed by the **noun** or the **verb**. There is no single noun in Spanish that matches the word in English. There just is not. Only a phrase: creerse con el derecho etc. o sentirse con el derecho de etc.

Comment: @walen It means that I am not confusing anything here at all in English as you suggested: "quizá Lambie al mezclar el común "to be entitled" con el negativo "sense of (self-)entitlement". Es imposible.

Comment: @walen Yes, I am saying that here there is no way I'm confusing these English words and, in general also, I don't. I spend my days (and often nights) reading and/or translating (into English, only). And I also do legal interpreting (Spanish<>English) for depositions, etc.

Comment: The word "privilegio" or "privilegiado" occurred to me. I checked the DLE and found no hint of negativity, and likewise found no negative or perjorative connotation for privelege in English. However, like "entitled," it can also be readily recognized as disparaging or uncomplimentary in everyday English of EU: a "privileged character," with  a "sense of entitlement." My question for native Spanish speakers is: does "privilegio" have any of the same deprecatory sense? It seems natural, since people readily resent privileges or entitlements enjoyed by others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En español existe el verbo **arrogar**, que en su forma pronominal **arrogarse** significa:

> **[arrogar[se]](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3mqbElW)**
>
> 2. prnl. Apropiarse indebida o exageradamente de cosas inmateriales, como facultades, derechos u honores.

El adjetivo que define a quien se arroga algo es, ni más ni menos, **arrogante**:

> **[arrogante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3mpjP8k)**
>   Del ant. part. act. de *arrogar*; lat. *arrŏgans, -antis*.
>
> 1. adj. Altanero, soberbio.

Y la cualidad de quien es arrogante o se arroga algo es la **arrogancia**:

> **[arrogancia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3mpiSEV)**
>   Del lat. *arrogantia*.
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de **arrogante**.

Otros sinónimos para arrogante/arrogancia son altivo/altivez, altanero/altanería, soberbio/soberbia, orgulloso/orgullo... Pero creo que **arrogante** y **arrogancia** son las palabras que más se aproximan al **sentido negativo** en inglés de *entitled* y *entitlement*.

Comment: Creo que has dado en el clavo. En la web definicion.de dice en la entrada de **arrogancia**: _«El individuo arrogante siente un orgullo excesivo sobre su persona y exige un reconocimiento desmedido, creyéndose con derecho a tener privilegios que, en realidad, no tiene ni le corresponden.»_

Comment: No creo que connnoten lo mismo

Comment: Basicamente -y de acuerdo a tu definicion- un arrogante denota alguien altanero o soberbio. Esa es su principal cualidad. Probablemente por ser altanero la persona sea "entitled"- espere merecerse todo- pero esa es una cualidad secundaria. Entitled por otro lado denota alguien que cree merecer todo como cualidad principal. Si es arrogante o no- es secundario

Comment: For my money _apropriarse_ in the defintion makes this a bit too active. People with a sense of entitlement tend to be rather passive. I suspect other L1 English speakers might disagree with me though.

Comment: Conozco personas que son totalmente "entitled" y que no son para nada arrogantes. En latinoamerica he escuchado una palabra para esas personas pero desafortunadamente es slang, no es espanol y ademas es algo grosera. Fuera de esa, no puedo imaginar que haya una palabra para entitled, desafortunadamente. A veces algunos idiomas no tienen palabras adecuadas.

Comment: arrogancia etc. nada tiene que ver con to be entitled to something. Absolutamente nada, lo lamento. **He thinks he's entitled to say whatever he wants. Cree que tiene el derecho de decir todo lo que piensa.**

Comment: @Lambie - OP pidió *entitlement* y no *entitled*.  *Entitlement* en el uso que describió OP, es más estrecho que *entitle* o *entitled*.

Comment: @aparente001 No hay substantivo en español para eso que no fuera con la palabra dercho. In English, the ment means state of being or feeling for this negative meaning:  el sentirse con derecho a todo. El -ment = el sentirse con. arrogarse un derecho o algo is not entitlement. It's granting yourself the right to something. It is very difficult for me to argue these points. As a 30+ professional translator across many disciplines, I think I know what I am saying here. A person may be arrogant if they feel entitled to blah blah blah, but entitlement is not arrogance per se.

Comment: @Lambie - I didn't say arrogance is the answer to this puzzle, or that the puzzle even has a solution.  (I haven't found one yet but I am giving it thought.)

Comment: @aparente001 Charlie and I are saying the same thing. I never said you said it was arrogance, did I? I don't think it is a puzzle at all.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien esta discusión, el OP pidió una palabra para un significado específico de "entitlement"  y la respuesta de @walen encaja perfectamente con ese significado concreto.

Comment: De acuerdo, puede haber otras alternativas y quizá mejores pero cuando se dice en varios comentarios que *entitlement* no implica arrogancia discrepo bastante. El significado que se busca es el de una persona que cree merecer ciertos privilegios por que sí, por que yo lo valgo, que alguien así no sea arrogante es practicamente imposible. Siempre hablando del sentido negativo que se pide en la pregunta.

Answer (score 8):

Se me ocurrían palabras como *[endiosamiento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FD8XHxL)* o *[titulitis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZtybZVR)*, pero me parece que la opción más adecuada la mencionas ya en la pregunta: "creerse con derecho a todo".

Te pongo ejemplos extraídos del CORDE, tanto de prensa como de novela:

> - Y desde luego que la multitud se ha instalado con todo aplomo en esta sociedad de consumo en la que todo el mundo se siente con derecho
>     a lo mejor, con derecho a todo.
> - La derecha, para el vicepresidente del Gobierno, se cree con derecho a todo "por derecho natural" y considera que la gente humilde, "como
>     los socialistas", no tiene derecho a nada.
> - Mark es uno de esos yanquis bestias que se creen con derecho a todo; un bruto ignorante que sólo tolera las novelas chicle: esos libros en
>     rústica que se compran en el aeropuerto junto con el periódico del
>     día, y se tiran a la basura a la llegada, junto al envoltorio del
>     chicle.
> - Se consideraba con derecho a todo porque su deber era hacer aún más evidente lo evidente.

Si prefieres especificar una situación concreta, también puedes usar "creerse con derecho a XXX":

> Más pareciera serlo de la audiencia que tuvo el afán declarativo de la magistrada Gisela Parra, quien acaso por ejercer en el organismo la representación del presidente de la República se creyó con derecho a olvidar su condición de integrante de un cuerpo colegiado cuyas posiciones obedecen al voto mayoritario de sus miembros y no al criterio personal de uno de ellos.

Comment: Why bother even mentioning them? You got it right. creerse con el derecho de todo o sentirse con el derecho de todo. :) This kind of question really bothers me because unless one has worked out the subtleties as you have here, it's hard to grasp. There is no noun in Spanish that covers it.

Answer (score 1):

La manera en la que yo lo suelo traducir (aparte de "*endiosamiento*", ya propuesto en otra respuesta) es con el término **"subidito,ta"** (que no es lo mismo que "estar subido" a secas).

En el DRAE tenemos

> **[subido, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YWtGe9c)**
>
> 1. adj. Último, más fino y acendrado en su especie.
> 2. adj. Muy elevado, que excede al término ordinario. *Precio subido*.

El término "subidito" al referirse a la actitud de alguien partiría de la tercera acepción de "subido" ("Elevado por encima de lo ordinario") pero con cierta connotación negativa, de **[prepotencia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=U4F3iyc)**, por el uso del diminutivo. Tocaría un poco con la primera acepción como "esa persona pretende elevarse a sí misma como lo 'Último, más fino y acendrado en su especie', como por encima de los demás (que somos el 'término ordinario')".

Por ejemplo

> Los de ese grupo están un poco *subiditos*. Se creen que son los más molones del instituto.
>
> Esa mujer está un poco *subidita*. Cualquier hombre que no sea Brad Pitt o Hugh Jackman es poco para ella.
>
> Creo que estás un poco *subidito* con el tema de las entrevistas de trabajo. Nadie te va a pagar lo que pides teniendo tu experiencia. Rebaja un poco tus expectativas para hacerlas más realistas.

Comment: Por cierto [acendrado, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0N4Lxzs): Dicho de algo como una cualidad, una conducta, etc.: Puro y sin mancha ni defecto.

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de ver, en un [sitio mexicano](https://www.muyinteresante.com.mx/curiosidades/sintomas-diagnostico-trastorno-personalidad-narcisista/) que habla sobre el narcisismo, el uso de la palabra "**merecimiento**":

> Las características principales de éste trastorno, de acuerdo con el *Manual de Diagnóstico de Trastornos Mentales*, son la sensación de grandiosidad, la búsqueda de admiración excesiva, **sensación de merecimiento** y de tratamiento especial, tomar ventaja de los demás y falta de empatía.

Comment: Este no es el lugar para agradecer y tener tertulias sobre el problema de esta palabra.  Es el epacio para contestar y esto no contesta la respuesta, sino pide más informacion.  Favor de hacer un comentario abajo de la pregunta y no aquí.

Comment: Como dice Karlomanio, se puede responder a un usuario mediante un comentario.  Para responder de manera más general, se puede editar el post.  La costumbre is poner tres guiones y luego "update:" o algo por el estilo.

Answer (score 1):

[Engreído](https://dle.rae.es/engre%C3%ADdo) puede valer.

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Demasiado convencida de su valer

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema más importante es el adjetivo.

Buscando en gallego llegué a varias opciones, que también valen para el castellano. Que os parece `REIVINDICATIVO`, o el syn. `RECLAMANTE`?

Lo de `arrogar/arrogante` (además de por su relación etimológica con `subrogar/surrogar`) me encantó.

`Petulante` se basa más en el carácter o la actitud que en la acción, y me da que ése es el foco en inglés. En el diccionario con el que trabajé la definición es ajustada, aunque no se centre en el hecho de que el derecho que se arroga no es real:

> Pedir o exigir [una cosa a la que se cree tener derecho]

".

Answer (score 0):

Como en muchas nuevas teorías, tecnologías y áreas de estudio, las palabras necesarias para expresar ciertos conceptos en el castellano simplemente no existen (el coaching es un excelente ejemplo), y el vocabulario debe ser prestado desde otro idioma, o inventado.

Nota la referencia al "entitlement" en paréntesis en [este artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcisismo):
"Jeffrey Young, que acuñó el término terapia de los esquemas (encuadrada en la terapia racional emotiva conductual), técnica originalmente desarrollada por Aaron T. Beck (1979), también relaciona la vergüenza con el TNP. Él ve el llamado esquema defectivo como un esquema nuclear en el TNP, próximo a los esquemas de deprivación emocional y de derechos, (Entitlement).8​ El esquema defectivo se compensa con tres modos de esquema (estrategias de emulación)..."

Creo que realmente no exista una sola palabra en castellano para expresar este rasgo del trastorno narcisista de la personalidad. Y si estoy equivocado, me encantaría que un **psicólogo** en América Latina o España me diga cuál es. (¡Por favor!)

Comment: "Being entitled" no es un trastorno de la personalidad. Es una actitud. "Creerse mejor que alguien o creerse con derecho a algo". Tu post no responde realmente a la pregunta. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: @Diego When exaggerated,it is most definitely a trastorno de la personalidad ("personality disorder). The orange man, for example. Feeling entitled to something, though, it is not always negative. That's where the OP is slightly off. We say to have feelings of entitlement. Charlie and I have both said basically the same thing about the term: sentirse con el derecho a todo o creerse con derecho a lo que sea. No hay subtantivo en español. Lo vengo diciendo desde mi primer comentario...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que las mejores traducciones serían petulante, presuntuoso o pretencioso.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21711)

Comment: What do you mean by this? How can this not be an appropriate answer?

Comment: It seems more like a commentary than an answer as it does not refer to any sources or definitions to back it up. See most of the other answers to see what I mean. It came up in the Low Quality Posts queue as the system had automatically flagged it. I agree the automatic message the system inserts is not very helpful.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sergio, una sugerencia: incluye en esta respuesta las definiciones del diccionario para esos términos. Así alguien puede ver qué es un [petulante](https://dle.rae.es/petulante?m=form) y decidir si la respuesta tiene mérito o no. Además, así en lugar de decir "La respuesta podría ser X", estarías diciendo "La respuesta podría ser X **por la razón Y**". Recuerda que una respuesta debe **explicar**. Si solo vas a recomendar a alguien que revise por su cuenta unos términos, entonces sí creo que eso debe ser un comentario y no una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Diego! Actualizaré la respuesta más adelante.

Answer (score -2):

Generalmente si se quiere expresar entitlement en el contexto descrito se usa la expresión: sentido de derecho

ej: Uno de los mayores problemas de esta generación es un alto sentido de derecho.

Comment: La traducción aportada no recoge para nada el sentido negativo que requirió en su día el OP.