# ¿Cuál es la secuencia más larga de definiciones circulares en el diccionario de la RAE?

Tags: definiciones, dle

A raíz de mi respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22937/13628), he descubierto en el DLE la siguiente definición circular:

- **[arrogante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3mpjP8k)** se define como altanero, soberbio.

  - [altanero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=268kv39) se define como altivo, soberbio.

    - [altivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=27iSyI7) se define como orgulloso, soberbio.

      - [orgulloso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RCCCTJW) se define como que tiene orgullo.

        - [orgullo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RCAtZVD) se define como arrogancia.

          - [arrogancia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3mpiSEV) se define como cualidad de **arrogante**.
  - [soberbio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y4X46Ep) se define como que tiene soberbia.

    - [soberbia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y4RxILC) se define como altivez.

      - [altivez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=27fucQf) se define como orgullo, soberbia... y de aquí otra vez **arrogante** según se ha visto antes.

Es cierto que hay otras definiciones y, en unos pocos casos, algún otro adjetivo adicional; pero igualmente me ha resultado curioso.

¿Hay más definiciones circulares de este tipo en el DLE? ¿Cuál sería la cadena 
 de definiciones más larga?

Comment: ¡La madre del cordero! Yo casi que propondría construir un grafo: los nodos serían los sustantivos, adjetivos y verbos, y las relaciones serían hacia las palabras (de los mismos tipos) que se usen en cada definición; una vez construido el grafo habría que ver cuál es el camino circular más grande dentro del grafo, seguro que hay alguna forma de calcularlo.

Comment: Bueno, creo que tiene que haber estos circuitos, ¿no?  Pero me frustraría si encontrara un circuito de sólo tres nodos.

Comment: Sadly @Charlie it is NP-hard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @walen - Nomás digo que entre menos nodos hay en el circuito, más me frustro con el diccionario.

Comment: @aparente001 igual podría ser interesante encontrar el bucle más corto, dado que el más largo seguramente acabe involucrando a todas las palabras de uso común.

Comment: Voté por cerrar por "too broad", porque no hay manera de resolver la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revisando el diccionario, se me presentó una respuesta autorreferente... se me vino una *duda* de como resolver esto y encontré que: (entre paréntesis, la acepción utilizada, en caso vacío es definición única)

- **[duda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EER7LDR)** (2): Vacilación del ánimo respecto a las creencias religiosas.

  - **[Vacilación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bEbtQdr)** (2): Perplejidad, irresolución

    - **[Irresolución](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M8jchvY)**: Falta de resolución

      - **[Resolución](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WB9Lgi3)** (1): Acción y efecto de resolver o resolverse.

        - **[Resolver](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC)** (1):  Solucionar un problema, una *duda*, una dificultad o algo que los entraña

En este caso, es un paso más corto del ejemplo original, pero por otra acepción, si bien es algo más forzado (teniendo en cuenta que si se toma el camino por otras palabras o se pierde el ciclo o se llega más rápido a la duda):

- **[duda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EER7LDR)** (1): Suspensión o indeterminación del ánimo entre dos juicios o dos decisiones, o bien acerca de un hecho o una noticia.

  - **[Indeterminación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LNGJ92B)**: Falta de determinación en algo, o de resolución en alguien.

    - **[Determinación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DaCIU9c)** (1): Acción y efecto de determinar o determinarse.

      - **[Determinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DaOWspV)** (1): Decidir algo, despejar la incertidumbre sobre ello.

        - **[Incertidumbre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BwLsxjt)**: Falta de certidumbre

          - **[Certidumbre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8OPyHv5)**(1): Certeza

            - **[Certeza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8OPnJP9)**: Conocimiento seguro y claro de algo

              - **[Seguro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XTrgHXd)**(2): Cierto, indubitable.

                - **[Cierto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Bb7pPO)**(2):  Conocido como verdadero, seguro, indubitable.

                  - **[Indubitable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LRLweyz)**:  Que no puede dudarse

                    - **[Dudar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EEYGVdk)** (1):  Tener *duda* sobre algo

La última, con 11 palabras conectadas, (teniendo en cuenta que el cierto entra *forzado*, pues lo seguro ya es indubitable.... o incluso ya hay resolución en la segunda definición lo que haría el círculo más corto), parece un buen ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Recordé la pregunta en estos días, me puse a jugar un rato y resultó lo siguiente (no escribo las definiciones completas por ahorrar espacio, solo la palabra del ciclo). Decidí dejar esta respuesta separada a la original ya que cada una costó su tiempo y su esfuerzo, si bien al revisar encuentro que hay cierta similitud entre la 'original' (duda con 5 palabras), y si el op lo prefiere las junto:

- **[valor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bJeLxWG)**: 8. Cualidad  del  ánimo (...)

  - **[ánimo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2hpXPBy)**: 3. (...), voluntad.

    - **[voluntad](https://dle.rae.es/?id=c2gSOgP)**: 5. (...) resolución

      - **[Resolución](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WB9Lgi3)**: 1. Acción y efecto de resolver (...)

        - **[Resolver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC)**: 2. Decidir (...)

          - **[Decidir](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BwLsxjt)** : 3. Hacer que (...)

            - **[Hacer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap)**: 4. Realizar (...)

              - **[Realizar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VHUV2Pi)**: 1. Efectuar (...)

                - **[Efectuar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EP1T95t)** 1. Poner por obra (...)

                  - **[Poner por obra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QnrhaT6%7CQo7V2Nd)** 1. Emprender (...)

                    - **[Emprender](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Esip2Nv)**  1. Acometer (...)

                      - **[Acometer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0X7ng6k)** 1. Embestir (...)

                        - **[Embestir](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EdV3cTI)** 1. Ir con ímpetu (...)

                          - **[Ímpetu](https://dle.rae.es/?id=L47htDT)** 4: Brío (...)

                            - **[Brío](https://dle.rae.es/?id=672nRvF)** : 2: (...), VALOR

y se cierra un ciclo con 15 palabras, que pudo ser más corto (de 3 palabras, de ánimo a resolución...) o al menos de 17 (el *brío* implica *espíritu*, al *efectuar* se puede *ejecutar* conservando el ciclo), lo que da muchas esperanzas a que sea posible un ciclo de definiciones que supere las 20 palabras...

Comment: Por cierto, Poner por obra es una locución incluida en el DLE, por si las moscas