# ¿Qué casos existen en el español de etimologías "cíclicas"?

Tags: etimología, dle, préstamo-lingüístico

En estos días leía acerca de reptiles y al buscar del tema en el DLE pude encontrar una curiosa etimología del [aligátor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1r7Qz06):

> **aligátor**
>
> Quizá del fr. *alligator*, este del ingl. *alligator*, y este del esp. *el lagarto*.

Además ayer planteaban la pregunta [¿Cuál es la secuencia más larga de definiciones circulares en el diccionario de la RAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22972/1674), y me llamó la atención la existencia de términos con "etimología circular" (en este **posible** caso, proviene del francés, a su vez del inglés y este último vuelve al español, aunque la palabra lagarto ya se nos va por otras lenguas).

¿Existen otros términos con etimologías que provengan del español? ¿Conocen un caso que "cruce" por más de 2 lenguas antes de volver al español la etimología de un vocablo?

Comment: En Barcelona se popularizó hace unos años hablar de _rambling_ para designar el hecho de pasearse por La Rambla. Inicialmente pensé que era un caso de estos, pues _ramblejar_ existe como verbo en catalán y parecería que se había importado del inglés después de "cedérselo". Sin embargo, veo que el verbo [_ramble_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ramble) en inglés viene de lenguas nórdicas.

Comment: ¿Se incluye una palabra como [*alcázar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1dQbAvd) en tu búsqueda, que se originó como palabra nativa pero luego pasó por el árabe antes de regresar?

Comment: Me viene a la cabeza [_popurrí_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tg7Igmg).

Comment: @tchrist en el DLE, el término alcázar lo dan como proveniente del latín. Quizás si tienes la fuente que pasa primero por el español antes de "entrar" al árabe, puesto que pudo conocerse en alguna otra parte del mediterráneo o en otra lengua de la península ibérica

Comment: @fedorqui Considero que eso es una confluencia de la palabra "Rambla" catalana con el verbo "ramble" inglés. Tu razonamiento es confuso. Presumiblemente haya un significado añadido en el contexto por parte de los hablantes ingleses visitantes a Barcelona.

Comment: Se me ocurre el topónimo Bahamas, que viene del español "bajamar".

Comment: Por si alguien está interesado en el italiano, pregunta equivalente a esta para esa lengua:  https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13005. ¡Gracias por esta idea tan interesante!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Si buscamos "del esp" en el DIRAE podemos ver algunos casos de palabras con etimologías circulares:

> **[sabir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WtVZv3y)**
>
> Del fr. *sabir*, y este de *saber*<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 1. m. Ling. Lengua franca de base románica.
>
> **[popurrí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tg7Igmg)**
>
> Del fr. *pot pourri*, y este calco de *olla podrida*.
>
> 1. m. Mezcolanza de cosas diversas, cajón de sastre.
> 2. m. Composición musical formada de fragmentos o temas de obras diversas.
>
> **[popelina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TfH1wAh)**
>
> Del fr. *popeline*, y este del esp. *papelina*<sup>2</sup>.
>
> 1. f. Cierta tela delgada, distinta de la papelina.
>
> **[tornado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a5qgcaS)**
>
> Del ingl. *tornado*, y este del esp. *tronada*.
>
> 1. m. huracán (‖ viento a modo de torbellino).

No he podido encontrar ningún caso de palabra que haya pasado por dos idiomas o más antes de volver al español.

Vamos a comprobar estas etimologías circulares buscando en otros diccionarios:

- El diccionario Larousse [dice que *sabir* proviene](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sabir/70354?q=sabir#69596) del "espagnol ou provençal *saber*, savoir". El etimológico del CNRTL [dice que viene](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sabir) del español.
- Para *popurrí*, el Larousse [confirma la etimología](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pot-pourri/63023?q=pot%20pourri#62312): "calque de l'espagnol *olla podrida*".
- Para *popelina*, el Larousse [niega que venga del español](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/popeline/62602?q=popeline#61899). De hecho dice que es una palabra con etimología circular para el francés, dado que vendría del inglés *poplin* y esta del francés *papeline*. El etimológico del CNRTL [parece confirmarlo](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/popeline), así que esta quedaría en estado dudoso.
- El Merriam-Webster [confirma que](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tornado) *tornado* proviene del español *tronada*.

Otra palabra con posible etimología circular no confirmada: *[banyo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ygwQJ3)*.

Comment: El Merriam-Webster acepta la procedencia española de la palabra inglesa *banjo*.

Comment: Tienes todas las opciones para quedar como respuesta, aunque prefiero ver si vienen otros ejemplos.

Comment: Español o francés papelina/papeline > inglés poplin > francés popeline > español popelina. Parece la evolución más logica

Comment: Todo esto a mí personalmente me resulta muy interesante y se me ha ocurrido preguntar lo mismo para la lengua italiana: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13005.

Answer (score 6):

Hay algunas otras palabras:

| palabra | etimología |
| --- | --- |
| [**albatros**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1WafCTl) | Del ingl. *albatross*, y este del esp. *alcatraz*. |
| [**mescalina**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P256wMC) | Del al. *Mezcalin* o *Meskalin*, y estos del esp. *mezcal* y el al. *-in* '-ina'. |
| [**charnego**](https://dle.rae.es/charnego) | Del cat. *xarnego*, y este del esp. *lucharniego*. |
| [**tostón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a9vA7vN) | Del port. *tostão*, y este del esp. *testón*. |
| [**apartamento**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=35x3ajw) | Del it. *appartamento*, y este del esp. *apartamiento*, con reducción de diptongo. |
| [**jade**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MI77Qow) | Del fr. *jade*, y este del esp. *[piedra de la] ijada*, porque el jade se aplicó por los conquistadores de América como remedio para aquella parte del cuerpo. |
| [**almorta**](https://dle.rae.es/almorta) | Del mozár. *almorta*, y este del esp. *muerta*. |
| [**batalán**](https://dle.rae.es/batal%C3%A1n) | Del tagalo *batalan*, y este der. del esp. *batea*. |
| [**cocoa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9bONNRu) | Del ingl. cocoa.<sup>1</sup> |
| [**estuque**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=estuque) | Del fr. *stuc* o el cat. *estuc*.<sup>3</sup> |

Y posiblemente estas:

| palabra | etimología |
| --- | --- |
| [**banyo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ygwQJ3) | Del ingl. *banjo*, pronunciación relajada de *bandore*, y este quizá del esp. *bandurria*. |
| [**clisos**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=clisos) | Del caló *clisos*, este quizá del dialect. *clisarse* 'mirar fijamente', y este de *eclipsarse*. |
| [**rodancha**](https://dle.rae.es/rodancha) | Del cat. *rodanxa*, y este quizá del esp. dialect. *rodanja* 'rodaja'. |

---

<sup>**1.** From Spanish [*cacao*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocoa#Etymology_1) (from Classical Nahuatl *cacahuatl*), by confusion with *coco*<sup>2</sup>, popularized by Samuel Johnson's A Dictionary of the English Language.</sup>
<sup>**2.** From Spanish/Portuguese [*coco*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coco#Etymology) (“grinning face”)</sup>
<sup>**3.** Etim.: del cast. [*estuco*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=estuc&Id=66823&search=estuc) o it. *stucco*, mat. sign.</sup>

Comment: https://iedra.es/palabras/?q=%22y+este+de%22&search_scope=e&search_type=e

Comment: https://iedra.es/palabras/?search_scope=e&accent=&search_type=e&q=%22y+este+del+espa%C3%B1ol%22