# Etimología de "fullería"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Una expresión coloquial que solemos usar mucho es "hacer fullerías":

> **[fullería](https://dle.rae.es/fuller%C3%ADa)**
>
> `De`*`fullero.`*
>
> 1. f. Trampa y engaño que se comete en el juego.
> 2. f. Astucia, cautela y arte con que se pretende engañar.

Si ahondamos en las palabras, encontramos:

> **[fullero, ra](https://dle.rae.es/fullero)**
>
> `De`*`fulla.`*
>
> 1. adj. Que hace fullerías. U. t. c. s.

Seguimos y aquí es donde viene el misterio:

> **[fulla](https://dle.rae.es/fulla)**
>
> `Del dialect.`*`fulla`*`'hoja'.`
>
> 1. f. *Hues.* Mentira, falsedad.

Veo pues que *fullería* proviene de una palabra *fulla* que solo se usa en Huesca, y que además proviene de una voz que significa "hoja". Luego pregunto, ¿cómo es posible que una hoja haya derivado en "hacer trampas"?

Voz harto antigua, por cierto:

> *Mas, si por dezir mentiras es vil vna arte, no sé yo quál lo es más en el mundo que la Poética, que toda ella es mentira y fullería.*
>
> Alonso López Pinciano, ["Filosofía antigua poética"](http://eva.fhuce.edu.uy/pluginfile.php/10004/mod_resource/content/0/LOPEZ-PINCIANO-Filosofia-antigua-poetica.pdf), 1596 (España).

Comment: "Huesca" parecería implicar que la palabra viene del aragonés ([*fuella*](https://oc.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragon%C3%A9s#Fonologia)) pero es más similar a la palabra catalán ([*fulla*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=fulla&Id=73417&search=fulla)).

Comment: ¿Y, cuando el diccionario dice "Del dialect. *fulla*", a qué se refiere?

Comment: @Charo es la contracción de "dialectal", no sé mucho más aparte de eso. He visto en algunas fuentes que por proximidad puede venir del catalán o del valenciano.

Answer (score 2):

He visto algunas teorías que cuadran con el origen de *fullería* a partir de *fulla* 'hoja'. La primera ha sido en el *Fichero general* de la RAE, donde [una ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_F/LETRA_F_PDF/FULLA/00000016.pdf#xml=http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getpdfhits&u=4cdbdba7&DocId=4840845&Index=C%3A%5CdtSearch%5FIndices%5CINDEXF&HitCount=1&hits=b%20&SearchForm=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CFICHERO%5Fform%2Ehtml%3F%5Fsm%5Fb%3DaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaR&.pdf) dice:

> Se trata del val. *fulla* 'carta, naipe', voz del juego de naipes donde "una fulla es una carta". En el juego, al jugar cartas para no descubrir el juego que se lleva, para tantear, para engañar a los contrarios, da lugar a hablar de "*fulla*, engaño, *falsa*, etc." > *fulla* 'engaño, falsedad'.

Es decir, en este caso la voz *fulla* no sería 'hoja' sino 'naipe'. Por otro lado, el *Etimológico* de Corominas dice:

> [...] su actual proximidad [de Aragón] a Cataluña hace pensar en que venga realmente del cat. *fulla* 'hoja' o *full* 'hoja de papel'. Sabido es que una de las trampas más corrientes consiste en marcar los naipes, para conocerlos, con algún doblez u otra señal: bien pudo esto llamarse 'hacer hoja' y pasar de ahí *fulla* a 'arte del tramposo'. Y, por otra parte, *full* es también «defecto que altera la homogeneidad en algún punto de una masa» [...], *fullat* 'pieza de loza que tiene *full*', *fuller* 'cuchillo con el mismo defecto' [...]: así *fuller* pudo significar 'de mala calidad, fallado' y aplicarse luego en castellano al jugador de mala condición, tramposo.

Corominas, por tanto, asocia *fulla* a la posibilidad de que las cartas se marcasen de algún modo, usando una expresión que contenía dicha palabra. O bien, si como menciona en un texto previo es *fulla* la que deriva de *fullero* y no al revés, *fullero* podría venir de *fuller* 'defectuoso', de *[full](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=full&Id=73415&search=full)* 'defecto'. Cita además un refrán para reforzar su teoría: «en la casa del ferrer, ganivet fuller» (me atrevería a traducirlo como "en casa del herrero, cuchillo fullero"). Aunque creo que en catalán sería "a casa del ferrer...".

Comment: Sí, es el famoso "En casa del herrero, cuchillo de palo", pero lo de ["ganivet fuller"](https://pccd.dites.cat/?paremiotipus=A+cal+ferrer%2C+ganivet+de+fusta) no lo había oído nunca. Y no encuentro "fuller" en el *Diccionari de l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans*.

Comment: Lo he encontrado [aquí](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp), pero dice que viene del castellano "fullero". ¿Se trata de un pez que se muerde la cola?

Comment: @Charo puede que se trate de un caso de [etimología cíclica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22988/12637) en catalán.

Comment: Según el DLE, la voz *ful* (falso, fallido) tiene su orígen en germanías. Claro que eso no impide que, a su vez, venga del catalán. En mi casa se usa bastante el adjetivo *fulero, -a* con el sentido de estropeado. También para personas: si digo que *estoy un poco fulero*, quiero decir que no me encuentro bien del todo, y si *la tele está fulera*, no funciona bien.