# ¿Deben las definiciones del DLE ser autosuficientes?

Tags: definiciones, rae, dle

El otro día buscando la palabra *[solfa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YHjDMEE)* en el DLE me encontré con que una de las acepciones no se entendía por si misma:

> 4. f. Combinación de ambas.

Me pareció raro ya que yo pensaba que las definiciones debían ser autosuficientes y esa definición necesita de la anterior para cobrar sentido:

> 3. f. Melodía y armonía.

Ahora ya parece que podemos presumir que cuando dice *ambas* se refiere a la *melodía* y la *armonía*.

¿Hay otras definiciones de este tipo o es un error? ¿Hay un criterio definido por la RAE para las definiciones en su diccionario?

Comment: También son a veces cíclicas: [¿Cuál es la secuencia más larga de definiciones circulares en el diccionario de la RAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22972/5481)

Comment: Tengo la sensación de que no hay criterios fijos en algunos casos, y de que a veces depende del académico que elaboró o revisó cada definición. Algo similar ocurre con las enciclopedias, donde se asignan artículos a distintos profesionales: cada uno impodrá su propio estilo.

Comment: [Recursion Through Dictionary Definition Space: Concrete Versus Abstract Words](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.3445&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [Loops and Self-Reference in the Construction of Dictionaries](https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.2.031018), [Self reference in word definitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2325), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según la RAE, las acepciones deben ser autosuficientes. Les pasé tu duda a través de Twitter y me respondieron [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/973917738069643266):

> En efecto, las acepciones deben ser autosuficientes. El caso que usted señala es un error que subsanaremos lo antes posible. Gracias por su observación.

Así que ya sabes, si en la próxima edición del diccionario aparece corregida la definición de *solfa*, ya podrás considerarte parte del DLE. :-)

En cuanto a si hay alguna palabra más con definiciones que no sean autosuficientes, busqué a través del [DIRAE](http://dirae.es) mediante palabras clave como "combinación" o "cualquiera" pero no encontré nada relevante.

Comment: Enhorabuena a ambos. No es una contribución insignificante ayudar a mejorar nada menos que el DLE.

Comment: @Charlie ya tiene experiencia con eso, para mi es nuevo. Estaré atento a ver si lo cambian

Comment: Casi cinco años y sigue sin subsanarse.