# Entendiendo la definición de "récord"

Tags: significado, definiciones, sustantivos, dle

El DLE define la palabra *récord* de la siguiente forma:

> **[récord](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%A9cord)**
>
> `Del ingl.`*`record`*.
>
> 1. m. **marca** (‖ mejor resultado en el ejercicio de un deporte).
> 2. m. Resultado máximo o mínimo en otras actividades. U. m. en apos.

Me surgen un par de dudas con respecto a esa segunda acepción.

- En la pregunta *[¿Deben las definiciones del DLE ser autosuficientes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24459/12637)* la RAE nos confirmó que las definiciones de las palabras deben ser autosuficientes. En la mencionada acepción se dice "en otras actividades", por lo que parece que para entender esa definición hay que leer antes la anterior, que menciona los deportes. ¿Es esta definición pues autosuficiente o deberíamos proponer a la RAE su modificación?
- ¿Qué significa que se usa más en [aposición](https://dle.rae.es/aposici%C3%B3n)? ¿Cuál sería un ejemplo de la palabra usada de esa forma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dado que la segunda definición refiere a la primera, sin la cual es imposible entenderla, la misma no es autosuficiente, violando así (de manera bastante tonta, añadiría yo) las reglas que la propia RAE se impuso. También es una definición demasiado estricta, ya que al hablar de “actividades” queda implícito que sólo se puede aplicar a acciones con un agente, siendo que es muy habitual hablar de récords de temperatura o precipitaciones (eventos atmosféricos).

Una [aposición](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sustantivos-en-aposicion/#:%7E:text=Una%20aposici%C3%B3n%20es%20una%20construcci%C3%B3n,invariable%20en%20cuanto%20al%20n%C3%BAmero.) es

> una construcción con dos sustantivos juntos, el segundo de los cuales modifica, matiza o complementa al primero. En este tipo de expresiones, solo el primer sustantivo suele llevar la marca de plural, quedando el segundo como invariable en cuanto al número.

Esta definición se refiere a sintagmas nominales compuestos como “hombre rana” o “ciudad dormitorio”. Dado que “récord” es considerado un sustantivo, esta es la forma de explicar que exista la alternancia entre “un récord de ganancias” y “ganancias récord” (que no son estrictamente hablando lo mismo).

También se usa “aposición” para referirse al lugar sintáctico de frases aclaratorias como “mi tío, **el de Buenos Aires**...” y las que tienen la estructura de “el tonto de tu padre” o “un encanto de persona”.