# ¿La palabra "sexo" hace referencia únicamente a relaciones con penetración?

Tags: definiciones, dle, sexualidad

Quiero saber si la palabra "sexo" hace referencia únicamente a relaciones con penetración o no.

Según el diccionario online de la RAE:

> [Sexo](https://dle.rae.es/sexo) 4. m. Actividad sexual.

y

> [Sexual](https://dle.rae.es/sexual?m=form) 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al sexo.

¿No es una contradicción definir las palabras de esta forma?

Comment: Qué definición circular tan rápida! Sobre eso, véase [¿Cuál es la secuencia más larga de definiciones circulares en el diccionario de la RAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22972/1674)

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "hacía"? ¿Se trata del uso del término en el pasado, frente al actual?

Comment: No tengo problema con que editen la pregunta si quieren corregir algo.

Comment: No quería hacer referencia a nada en especial cuando usé el pretérito imperfecto. Tendría que haber usado presente del indicativo. Ya edité la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se refiere a dos personas teniendo relaciones sexuales sí **suele** implicar penetración pero del término per se no se puede inferir, ya que puede aplicarse a uno mismo con su mecanismo. Perdón por emplear un eufemismo trasnochado.

[**masturbar**](https://dle.rae.es/masturbar)

> 1. tr. Estimular los órganos genitales o las zonas erógenas con la mano o por otro medio para proporcionar goce **sexual**.

La definición que aportas es económica más que contradictoria

[**sexo**](https://dle.rae.es/sexo?m=form)

> 3. m. Órganos sexuales.

[**sexual**](https://dle.rae.es/sexual)

> 4. Perteneciente o relativo al sexo

Podemos desglosar esta cuarta acepción como

> Perteneciente o relativo a los órganos reproductores que marcan la condición másculina o femenina

Rompiendo así la circularidad infinita que tú llamas contradictoria.

Comment: Bien explicado. La circularidad es estricta si _sexual_ se define tomando solamente la 4.ª acepción de _sexo_. Si se toman todas, ya no.