# ¿Es posible una definición cíclica de conque?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, conjunciones

Ayer (21 de junio de 2021) la palabra del día del DLE fue [conque](https://dle.rae.es/conque?m=form). Me pareció curioso en particular el tercer significado de la palabra que dice:

> 3. m. coloq. Condición con que se hace o se promete algo.

El *con que* de esa definición ¿No podría remplazarse con la palabra conque, en su primera definición? so pena de una definición *cíclica* de la palabra.

Comment: Reemplazar "con que" por "conque" ahí solo sería una falta de ortografía. La palabra "condición" no constituye un "enunciado" completo del que puede extraerse como consecuencia "se hace".

Comment: Una definición cíclica? ¿Qué es?

Comment: @Lambie es una definición circular, como puedes ver en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-secuencia-m%c3%a1s-larga-de-definiciones-circulares-en-el-diccionario-de

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? Con que, Con qué y conque

- Con que es sinónimo de "con el cual" ó "con la cual";
- Con qué se usa en oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas, mientras que
- Conque es una conjunción ilativa que equivale a "así que", "por tanto" ó "por consiguiente". Expresa consecuencia

Como tal, son palabras homófonas, es decir, que suenan igual pero se escriben de manera diferente.

Así pues, el "*con que*" de la definición, pertenecería al primer punto.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos!

Diego M